# how can i replace my redux actions and use create actions library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga, redux-actions

I'm looking for redux libraries that can reduce redux boilerplate 
and recently i discovered reduxsouce and redux-actions which helps in reducing action object code rewrite. In all my previous projects for action definition i would creat one file for all actions 
and 
actions looks like this

```
export function requestInit() {
  return {
    type: types.REQUEST_INIT,
    payload: {
      loading: true,
    },
  };
}
```

now if i want to remove action definition and switch to "createaction" how can i replace this with createaction method from redux-actions?

also how do i handle or "put" other fail or success action from saga
(generator function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the redux-action [docs](https://redux-actions.js.org/api/createaction), the actions definitions should look like this:

```
import { createAction, handleAction } from 'redux-actions';
const defaultState = { loading: false };

export const requestInit = createAction(types.REQUEST_INIT); // creates an action creator

// Define your reducer here, as second argument. 
// First argument is the action type, third is defaultState
handleAction(
  types.REQUEST_INIT,
  (state, action) => ({
    loading: action.payload.loading
  }),
  defaultState
);
...
// in saga.js or other place you want to use the action
requestInit({ loading: true });
```

In the same manner you could add other actions to handle your requests. Dispatching and handling errors should be exactly as it is with ordinary actions, i.e.:

```
yield put({ type: response, payload: {...} });
```

Hope that's helpful.